# Unable to use aggregate in mongoose from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in mongodb named 'users' and 'posts'

users look like this:-

```
[
    {
      "_id": "5e3ffba65bad3a38dc0509cd",
      "name": "Ekansh Jain",
      "email": "ejekanshjain@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2a$10$lF1evuJgfC0N7fIC4I7KrOG.lq56aiHzndIYwc/YRb3auLTgHfmGK",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-09T12:31:34.117Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-02-09T12:31:34.117Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e403dcd1000793694bd2276",
      "name": "Ekansh Jain",
      "email": "ejekanshjain2@gmail.com",
      "password": "$2a$10$qGmng4KrXVXKt0RLnSMgMueo.BenKM43QIpURrzxW4M.HGDHe//TC",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-09T17:13:49.508Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-02-09T17:13:49.508Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
]
```

posts look like this

```
[
    {
      "_id": "5e403aa22a28e430b0d2641a",
      "title": "My Post 1",
      "body": "this is my first post's body",
      "createdBy": "5e3ffba65bad3a38dc0509cd",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-09T17:00:18.991Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-02-09T17:00:18.991Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "userInfo": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e403e8b1000793694bd2278",
      "title": "LOL",
      "body": "LOL",
      "createdBy": "5e403dcd1000793694bd2276",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-09T17:16:59.513Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-02-09T17:16:59.513Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "userInfo": []
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e46c8cfe56d4325b4e8d334",
      "title": "test Post",
      "body": "this is my first post's body",
      "createdBy": "5e3ffba65bad3a38dc0509cd",
      "createdAt": "2020-02-14T16:20:31.771Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-02-14T16:20:31.771Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "userInfo": []
    }
]
```

I have two mongoose models in my nodejs express application named User and Post.

I am not able to aggregate (unable apply inner join on the posts and user)

Here's the code I am currently using right now :-

```
const posts = await Post.aggregate([
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "users",
                    "localField": "createdBy",
                    "foreignField": "_id",
                    "as": "userInfo"
                }
            }
        ]).exec()
```

In the result, it returns array of objects of posts with empty userInfo object.
Can someone help me out with this...

Comment: If `"createdBy"` is a string you need to convert it into `ObjectId()` to match with `_id` of users. So what is the type of `createdBy` ?

Comment: _id is ObjectId() and createdBy is string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `createdBy` is a string & `_id` is of type `ObjectId()`, then You need to bring both fields to same type, try this :

```
Post.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: "users",
            let: { createdBy: "$createdBy" },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match:
                    {
                        $expr:
                            { $eq: [{ $toObjectId: "$$createdBy" }, "$_id"] }
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "userInfo"
        }
    }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g1xhfV31mI3)

**Note :** Alternatively if you don't want to convert these every time you need to store `createdBy` as `ObjectId()`.

So in your `Post` model `createdBy` type should be `Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

while saving Post document `createdBy : mongoose.Types.ObjectId('someString');`